# Weather API data request

Tags: node.js, rest, axios, ejs

I have this ejs template that inputs the name of the city, the city gets stored into the database and then display the related weather result. I created a controller to POST the city from that input box. The city name gets stored easily and gets a success message but it does not pass that city to the GET request into the weather API URL to display the related weather details.

Here is my controller for city:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const axios = require('axios');
const City = require('../models/city');

exports.addCity = (req, res, next) => {
    const city = new City({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        cityName: req.body.cityName
    });
    city
        .save()
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            res.status(201).json({
                message: "Created city successfully"
            });
        })

        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            });
        });
};


exports.getCity = (req, res, next) => {

    City.find({}).then(docs => {
            cities: docs.map(doc => {
                return {
                    city: doc.cityName
                }
            })

            let apiKey = '**************************';
            var city = cities;
            var url= `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${apiKey}`;
            axios(url)

            .then( (response) => {

                var cityData = response.data;

                var weather = {
                    city: city,
                    temperature: Math.round(cityData.main.temp),
                    description: cityData.weather[0].description,
                    icon: cityData.weather[0].icon
                }

                // var weather_data = { weather : weather };

                console.log('heyyyy', weather);

                res.render('index', {
                    weather: weather
                });
            })
            .catch( (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        });
})

}
```

And here is the snippet of the ejs template:

```
                     <article class="media">
                            <div class="media-left">
                                <figure class="image is-50x50">
                                    <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/<%= weather.icon %>.png" alt="Image">
                                </figure>
                            </div>
                            <div class="media-content">
                                <div class="content">
                                    <p>
                                        <span class="title"><%= weather.city %></span>
                                        <br>
                                        <span class="subtitle"><%= weather.temperature %></span>
                                        <br> <%= weather.description %>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </article>
```

Whenever I run my localhost, it only creates the city into the database and display console with the lots of error data back with last two lines saying:

```
data: { cod: '404', message: 'city not found' } } }
{ _id: 5c6d4e18d1ad342458c3df64, cityName: 'mumbai', __v: 0 }
```

Kindly help to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `getCity` controller you provided has some syntax errors but I tried my best to work with it. Main changes are 1. the logic to find matching document and 2. the way you construct the GET query using Axios

```
exports.getCity = (req, res, next) => {
  const cityName = req.query.cityName;

  City.find({})
    .then(docs => {

      // 1. Find matching city document
      const city = docs.find(doc => {
        return doc.cityName === cityName;
      });

      if (city) {
        const apiKey = "**********";
        const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather";

        // 2. Axios GET query with params as object instead of interpolating inside url
        axios
          .get(url, {
            params: {
              q: city.cityName,
              appId: apiKey
            }
          })
          .then(response => {
            const cityData = response.data;

            const weather = {
              city: city,
              temperature: Math.round(cityData.main.temp),
              description: cityData.weather[0].description,
              icon: cityData.weather[0].icon
            };
            // Do something with weather
            console.log(weather);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            // Weather query failed
            console.log(err);
          });
      } else {
        // No city found matching cityName
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // Database fetch failed
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the syntactical. I tried it, but it's still not able to render the 'index.ejs'. It's consoling 'weather' object as undefined in the index file.

Comment: Are you able to console.log the weather object inside the promise on resolve?

Comment: Yes, I tried to console it. But it shows nothing. Maybe it's not even entering that console because I have added **res.render('index', weather: weather)** before the console, so it gets the error at that point only.